# How do I have a ruby program call into a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irc, sidekiq, cinch

I want to write a cinch IRC bot that sends information to a rails application.  The rails application will essentially function as a monitor for users, and theoretically the data displayed will continually refresh.

I have the basic IRC bot working on it's own and have written standalone rails applications before.  I do not know what the best way to integrate them together is though? Using sidekiq could start the bot, but it does not give me a clean way to connect back into the website.

Comment: sounds like you should build an api (rest api maybe) into your rails app.

Comment: I don't want to have to send packets to the local webserver. That's extra delay that seems wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options:

1. Build an api and let your script send requests to that api endpoint
2. Use `script/runner` to call your methods in your app directly
3. Let the script store data directly into the apps database

I think the api solution is the only reasonable option for security and maintainablity reasons.

Comment: Think performance will be good enough if I'm using the api system?

Comment: The apis I have in use have average response times between 10-30ms. That depends a bit on what transformations or calculations you need to do before you can store the payload. How many requests to you expect per hour/minute/second?

Comment: We are integrating with twitch, but doubt that our channels will be too popular. At most a hundred probably. Ideally the bot puts something in a queue that the rails app consumes.